# How can I load data into BigQuery without ProtoBuf format error?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

In [loading data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-cloud-datastore), I get the following error (copied from Job History in BigQuery web console).

```
Errors:
query: Failed to load FileDescriptorProto for '_GEN_DREMEL_ONESTORE_METADATA_SCHEMA_': (error code: invalidQuery)
 Field numbers 19000 through 19999 are reserved for the protocol buffer library implementation.
 Field numbers 19000 through 19999 are reserved for the protocol buffer library implementation. 
 [... repeated a total of exactly 1000 times...]
 Field numbers 19000 through 19999 are reserved for the protocol buffer library implementation. 

 (error code: invalidQuery)
```

The data is a Datastore Managed Backup. (The folks from that team sent me to BigQuery for help.)

The error occurs with one of six randomly selected Kinds; the others load successfully.  In addition, loading another Kind gives the error "too many fields: 10693 (error code: invalid)".

Both the failed Kind and the successful ones have a similar size of ~15 gigabytes of data.

What can we do to load this data?

Comment: Thank you for your report. Do you have a job_id that we can look at?

Comment: bquijob_5ae806a6_157d8486814 produces "too many fields: 10693 (error code: invalid)". And bquijob_2129fd00_157a9f47a5d  produces the "reserved for the protocol buffer library" message.

Please message me offline if you'd like more info (so we can keep the specifics private).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by BigQuery's  [limitation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy): A maximum of 10000 columns per table.  So the utility for loading a Datastore backup simply does not work in this case.